# Is there any python/pytorch library that generates patches and labels of a bigger Image(labeled)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, object-detection

I am currently trying to solve a mitosis object detection problem and it seems that I have to feed it many patches of labeled images since the actual input data is 7000x5000 pixels in size. I looked into many different sites but all they show is how to generate patches of the image but **not with the labels**. I'm currently stuck with this problem and don't know how to solve it anyhow. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Does this help https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation